# Understanding the Final-value Theorem in the Laplace Transform Theory

Tags: laplace-transform

I am an Electrical Engineering student and I study from the book "Engineering Circuit Analysis 8th Ed." authored by Hayt, Kemmerly and Durbin. On Chapter 14, page 562 dealing with an **COMPLEX FREQUENCY AND THE LAPLACE TRANSFORM**, there is a subsection on the Final-Value Theorem.

[image: Final-value]

> The math in the above mentioned steps seems pretty straightforward to me except that I don't understand why this Final-Value Theorem works only for those $\mathrm{F(s)}$ whose poles lie entirely in the left half of the $\boldsymbol s$ plane, i.e for $\sigma < 0$. Why is such an assumption taken?

This is not a subject covered in my class but only something I found in the book. That being said, it won't be covered in our exams but still, I want to have a moment of epiphany where I get to understand how things work. That being said, I would be really grateful if someone finds the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions with Laplace transforms that have poles in the right half plane don't have a final value. Take $e^t-1$, for example. Its Laplace transform is

$$\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}= \frac{1}{s(s-1)}$$

and the Final Value Theorem would have you believe that

$$e^{\infty} - 1 = -1$$

which is clearly absurd.

Comment: I want to remark that even having poles only on the imaginary axis is not enough. Take the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2+1} \to 1 - \cos t$$ and again Final Value Theorem would mislead you because $$ 1 - \cos \infty \neq 1$$

Comment: OK. So there is a missing text in the book. The function $f(t)$ of interest should not have poles on the $j\omega$ axis as well. Thank you!

Comment: @billyandriam The text was not missing, the textbook was correct all along. Notice that they said that all of the poles must lie entirely in the left half plane. Although I will say that left half plane + the origin would be the more technically correct statement, because otherwise the limit would always be $0$.

Comment: I also have a question about the math involved in the initial-value theorem. That would be my last request. Thanks in advance :). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435147/understanding-the-initial-value-theorem-in-the-laplace-transform-theory