# Understanding the Initial-value Theorem in the Laplace Transform Theory

Tags: laplace-transform

I am an Electrical Engineering student and I study from the book "Engineering Circuit Analysis 8th Ed." authored by Hayt, Kemmerly and Durbin. On Chapter 14, page 562 dealing with an **COMPLEX FREQUENCY AND THE LAPLACE TRANSFORM**, there is a subsection on the **Initial-Value Theorem**.

[image: Initial-value]

Now, what don't understand is the part where the initial integral is split into two:

$$
\lim_{s\to\infty}\left(\int_{0^{-}}^{\infty} e^{-st}\frac{df}{dt}dt\right) = \lim_{s\to\infty}\left(\int_{0^{-}}^{0^+} e^{0}\frac{df}{dt}dt + \int_{0^{+}}^{\infty} e^{-st}\frac{df}{dt}dt\right)
$$

> Why did $e^{-st}$ become $e^{0}$ in the first part of the split integral when taking the limit to infinity? I have taken Calculus course before but I am just lost in here ($s$ is a complex number in this context).

I would be really grateful if someone answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very hand wavy way, what is the only number between $0^+$ and $0^-$? $0$, of course. So the only number that gets plugged in for $t$ is $0$. However, this is a terrible way to prove the Initial Value Theorem. Here is a better way. We already have that

$$\int_0^\infty f'(t) e^{-st}dt = sF(s) -f(0)$$

Then taking $s\to\infty$, and assuming $f'(t)$ was bounded, we get that

$$\int_0^\infty f'(t)\cdot 0 dt = 0 = \lim_{s\to\infty} sF(s) -f(0)$$

Comment: Why is it terrible?